# How can I make my navigation bar (which has transparent background) to float/overlap my background in a parallax-scrolling webpage?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to design a webpage where navigation bar has no background and it floats over background image. However, This being a parallax-scrolling website, as soon as page is scrolled to second section, my navigation bar pushed the background down by the size of it's own width.

I require it to float over my sections.

Thanks.

Comment: 1. post the code of what your attempting it will make answering easier.
To Fix: 1. position the navigation bar absolute, or 2. shift the naviagation bar with the parallax scrolling so it stays in position

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather vague.

Where do you want the navigation bar to sit and at what size?

If you want the navigation bar to remain at the top of viewport throughout your sections, set it to,

`position fixed; top 0; left: 0; z-index: 1000;`

(with whatever height and width you desire)
then have your parallax layers on a carousel type parent DOM element